# improving performance time on a pd.date_range iteration for a large dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date-range

I have a very large dataset of dates and I am trying to calculate the number of days spent in each month. Below is a sample from the data set:

```
                LoadDate            DischDate
87364    01/07/2017 00:22:16  16/07/2017 08:10:55
745999   08/06/2017 19:38:06  12/06/2017 15:20:59
1870836  17/02/2018 19:51:15  10/04/2018 03:53:57
436131   17/11/2015 00:00:17  06/01/2016 11:00:01
984437   26/11/2016 14:48:47  15/12/2016 18:39:54
```

Using the following code I was able to find out the number of days, however the output is rounded up so instead of for example showing; 10.86 days spent in Mar-18 it would output 11 days instead.

```
dates.join(dates.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(pd.date_range(x.LoadDate, 
x.DischDate, freq='D')).dt.strftime('%m-%y'),1)
     .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(),1)
     .rename(columns=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%m-%y').strftime('%b-%y')))
```

I changed the frequency in the pd.date_range formula above from freq = 'D' to freq = 'T' to calculate minutes then divided by 1440 to get the number of days accurately. However this process is very time consuming even on a small sample of the dataset and will not be scalable at all.

eg code after changes:

```
dates.join(dates.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(pd.date_range(x.LoadDate, 
x.DischDate, freq='T')).dt.strftime('%m-%y'),1)
     .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(),1)
     .rename(columns=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%m-%y').strftime('%b-%y'))/1440)
```

How should I go about improving the performance of this code and being able to scale it for a 1.1gb size dataset.

Your help is much appreciated.

--
**black.mamba**

Comment: what are you defining as 'days'? total days? If so, I think timedelta will help you out with this. Each row has a corresponding timedelta, is that right?

Comment: days is the datafram or df if you will. It contains data for the two columns LoadDate and DischDate (Start and End date).

Comment: I am asking how you are defining this: ```I am trying to calculate the number of days spent in each month```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't exactly understand what you mean. However "dates" is included in my question as the first block of code. It is a dataframe with two columns indexed by an entry code. Hope that helps and I thank you for your time on this